# Fantasy book set on a desert world with the protagonist mind-melding with a cat

Tags: story-identification

I read a fantasy (?) series 25+ years ago, and it has strangely been on my mind. It took place on a desert-like world not unlike the Middle East.  Language was similar too.

Main character was a young man that mind-melded with a very large cat (reminds me of *Avatar*'s character with the flying creature). He rode on his back. This image was on the cover.

Answer (score 6):

I suspect you are talking about the [Gandalara Cycle](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gandalara_Cycle); see if these looks familiar.
[image: Gandalara Book Collections]

- **It took place on a desert-like world not unlike the middle east.** 
  Yep; although the details of where it was are a significant spoiler. (Not exactly a world, but 'their world', such that it is, is a desert.)
- **Language was similar too.** 
  Not addressed that much, but it is mentioned.  Rikardon's name, for example, is an example of foreshadowing, once you understand it's meaning.
- **Main character was a young man that mind-melded with a very large cat.** 
  Right near the start of the first book, Rikardon encounters Keeshah, the Sha'um (kind of resembles a sabre-toothed tiger) who he is surprised to discover he is mentally bonded to.  The nature of this bond is a major element of parts of the story.
- **He rode on his back. This imagine was on the cover.** 
  In fact, it's his main method of travelling.  It occurs on the attached cover of the first collection (above), but also on the covers of many of the single books. (example below)
  [image]

Comment: AWESOME!!!!  Thats it!!!   Now I must try and read it again.  I might not like it as much as I am decades older!